# How to add cash to a city government

Tags: cheats, capitalism-lab

I am playing *Capitalism Lab* with the *City Economic Simulation DLC*. Is there a way for players or companies to transfer cash to a city government to help it balance its budget? I may want to donate money to a city government to help it fund more civic buildings and sports facilities, or to help it avoid bankruptcy.

If a donation is not possible, is there a cheat to increase the cash of a city government? The <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> cheat for adding $10 million to a company's cash balance has no effect on a city's cash balance, even when a member of my political party is the mayor of that city.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways:

1. Buy land. The proceeds from land purchases goes to the city government. However, when the player sells the land, it is sold back to the city government, which will reduce the city government's cash.
2. If the city government owns media firms, then advertise through those media firms to increase the city government's revenues. For example, one could set up this useless retail store whose real purpose is to transfer cash to the government via the government's television station:

[image: Cash transfer to city government via retail store advertising]